# Fatal Exception Caused by UIKit

Tags: ios, uikit

I have noticed a crash on my dashboard of Crashlytics but i don't have any idea why did it appeared, i think it caused by UIKit (Looks like something wrong with keyboard in iPhone 4S pls correct me if i'm wrong). I have posted log from Crashlytics. pls if anyone can give me a clue to solve this crash i'll appreciate.

```
# Crashlytics - plaintext stacktrace downloaded by xxx at Fri, 17 Nov 2017 13:18:33 GMT
# URL: xxx
# Organization: xxx’s Projects
# Platform: ios
# Application: xxx
# Version: 1.0 (1)
# Bundle Identifier: com.xxx.app
# Issue #: 48
# Issue ID: 5a0e8fda61b02d480d9dd90a
# Session ID: 40dd34a088804902ad63bd4a505cacaa_0d42b6facb6911e7b7d856847afe9799_0_v2
# Date: 2017-11-17T07:25:00Z
# OS Version: 9.3.5 (13G36)
# Device: iPhone 4s
# RAM Free: 39.6%
# Disk Free: 53.6%

#0. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  xxx                         0x68852d CLSProcessRecordAllThreads
1  xxx                         0x68852d CLSProcessRecordAllThreads
2  xxx                         0x688425 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads
3  xxx                         0x67bbc1 CLSHandler
4  xxx                         0x686cb3 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x24c9d80f _dispatch_client_callout
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x24ca901d _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke
7  xxx                         0x6866a7 CLSExceptionRecord
8  xxx                         0x6864cf CLSExceptionRecordNSException
9  xxx                         0x6860d1 CLSTerminateHandler()
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x248bce17 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x248bc8f9 __cxa_increment_exception_refcount + 98
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x248caf5f objc_exception_rethrow + 42
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2503f2af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 654
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2503f015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
15 GraphicsServices               0x2662fac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
16 UIKit                          0x29713189 UIApplicationMain + 144
17 xxx                         0x3454d1 main (main.m:14)
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x24ce7873 (Missing)

--

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2512f91b __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x248cae17 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2512f861 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  CoreFoundation                 0x250859c7 -[__NSCFString hasSuffix:]
4  UIKit                          0x29aae795 __49-[UIKeyboardImpl addInputEvent:executionContext:]_block_invoke
5  UIKit                          0x29fdb4a9 -[UIKeyboardTaskExecutionContext returnExecutionToParentWithInfo:]
6  UIKit                          0x29fdb4a9 -[UIKeyboardTaskExecutionContext returnExecutionToParentWithInfo:]
7  UIKit                          0x29aaf56f -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
8  UIKit                          0x29aaec77 -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
9  UIKit                          0x29aae56f -[UIKeyboardImpl addInputEvent:executionContext:]
10 UIKit                          0x29ab0ceb -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptPredictiveInput:executionContext:]
11 UIKit                          0x296d5615 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread]
12 UIKit                          0x29ab0a17 -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptPredictiveInput:]
13 UIKit                          0x29bb7815 -[UIKeyboardPredictionView acceptCandidateAtCell:]
14 Foundation                     0x2594daf5 __NSFireDelayedPerform
15 CoreFoundation                 0x250f258f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
16 CoreFoundation                 0x250f21c1 __CFRunLoopDoTimer
17 CoreFoundation                 0x250f000d __CFRunLoopRun
18 CoreFoundation                 0x2503f229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
19 CoreFoundation                 0x2503f015 CFRunLoopRunInMode
20 GraphicsServices               0x2662fac9 GSEventRunModal
21 UIKit                          0x29713189 UIApplicationMain
22 xxx                         0x3454d1 main (main.m:14)
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x24ce7873 (Missing)

#0. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  xxx                         0x68852d CLSProcessRecordAllThreads
1  xxx                         0x68852d CLSProcessRecordAllThreads
2  xxx                         0x688425 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads
3  xxx                         0x67bbc1 CLSHandler
4  xxx                         0x686cb3 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x24c9d80f _dispatch_client_callout
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x24ca901d _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke
7  xxx                         0x6866a7 CLSExceptionRecord
8  xxx                         0x6864cf CLSExceptionRecordNSException
9  xxx                         0x6860d1 CLSTerminateHandler()
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x248bce17 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x248bc8f9 __cxa_increment_exception_refcount + 98
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x248caf5f objc_exception_rethrow + 42
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2503f2af CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 654
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2503f015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
15 GraphicsServices               0x2662fac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
16 UIKit                          0x29713189 UIApplicationMain + 144
17 xxx                         0x3454d1 main (main.m:14)
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x24ce7873 (Missing)

#1. com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24dbc2f8 kevent_qos + 24
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x24cb1d61 _dispatch_mgr_invoke
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x24cb1abf _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp

#2. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24da68d0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24da66d5 mach_msg + 40
2  CoreFoundation                 0x250f1ac5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
3  CoreFoundation                 0x250efe4d __CFRunLoopRun + 1036
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2503f229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2503f015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
6  CFNetwork                      0x256909f7 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 486
7  Foundation                     0x259594a5 __NSThread__start__ + 1148
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e6385b _pthread_body + 138
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e637cf _pthread_start + 110
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61724 thread_start + 8

#3. com.apple.CFSocket.private
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24dbaeec __select + 20
1  CoreFoundation                 0x250f6f13 __CFSocketManager + 566
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e6385b _pthread_body + 138
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e637cf _pthread_start + 110
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61724 thread_start + 8

#4. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24da68d0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24da66d5 mach_msg + 40
2  xxx                         0x67730f CLSMachExceptionServer
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e6385b _pthread_body + 138
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e637cf _pthread_start + 110
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61724 thread_start + 8

#5. com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24da68d0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24da66d5 mach_msg + 40
2  CoreFoundation                 0x250f1ac5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
3  CoreFoundation                 0x250efe4d __CFRunLoopRun + 1036
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2503f229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2503f015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
6  Foundation                     0x25888045 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 268
7  xxx                         0x791f49 -[_FSRRunLoopThread main] (FSRWebSocket.m:1840)
8  Foundation                     0x259594a5 __NSThread__start__ + 1148
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e6385b _pthread_body + 138
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e637cf _pthread_start + 110
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61724 thread_start + 8

#6. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61710 start_wqthread + 14

#7. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24dbb864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61b35 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61718 start_wqthread + 8

#8. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24dbb864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61b35 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61718 start_wqthread + 8

#9. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24dbb864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61b35 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61718 start_wqthread + 8

#10. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61710 start_wqthread + 14

#11. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x24dbb864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61b35 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24e61718 start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: I saw very similar crash trace, but in my case it's an iPhone 5S, iOS 11.1.2.

Comment: Also for some reason I only see this crash report in Apple's own Crash analytics, but it didn't make it to my Firebase Crash reporting dashboard (pre-Crashlytics version).

Comment: @NikolaySuvandzhiev have you ever stopped this crash?

Comment: I didn't take any action, and I haven't seen crashes since.